# sessionStorage troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to understand how sessionStorage works. I get how to make it store some variable and restore it but I wanted to do something different.

[This link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show) from w3schools shows how to show/hide elements with a function. I have a pretty similar setup on my site. So I wanted to make it work on the w3schools example then I'll know how to apply it on my site.

Could you perhaps edit the w3schools code to make it use session storage to restore the last option (either shown or hidden) so that I can undestand how it works and apply it then myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got how to store/retrieve values so what are you missing? You've got all the tools you need.

Comment: [W3Schools web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="hideMe">some text</p>
    <button id="hide">hide</button>
    <button id="show">show</button>

    <script>    
        $(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#hideMe").hide()
        sessionStorage.setItem('hidden', 'true');
      })
      $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#hideMe").show()
        sessionStorage.setItem('hidden', 'false');
      })
      sessionStorage.getItem('hidden') === 'true' ? $("#hideMe").hide() : null
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1v84pejk/))

But I'd say it's not what you're looking for. The `sessionStorage` will survive page reloads but as soon as you close the tab/window it's gone.

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.
>   (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Nope, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I don't need it to survive tab close. Thanks though, that helps!

Comment: Alright, tell me if you need further explanation. Cheers